# Can't access GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I've created several repositories on GitLab and need to create more. This has worked for me in the past, but now I can no longer access.

So, please, how can I diagnose and fix?

My goal: I'm soon headed out of the country for an extended stay. I want to work on several projects on my notebook computer while I'm away.

I tried to create two new projects following the instructions "Existing Git Repository" on:

https://gitlab.com/writersglen/AntsleBook

But in both cases I get this when I try to push:

```
lloyd@wg-dev:~/WG/Books/Titles/Antsle$ git push -u origin --all

sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation

Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

So far as I can tell, I have the correct public key on GitLab.

I get a similar message when I try to pull from successfully created repositories.

So, I be very grateful if some kind soul can show me how to get out of this mess.

Best wishes,

LRP

Comment: Are you using SSH? What does `git remote -v` show?

Comment: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: Which directory did you execute the command from? Be sure you are in a directory in your git repo.

Comment: old-origin https://github.com/BuildItWithNitrogen/nnotec.git (fetch)
    old-origin https://github.com/BuildItWithNitrogen/nnotec.git (push)
    origin git@gitlab.com:writersglen/nnotec.git (fetch)
    origin git@gitlab.com:writersglen/nnotec.git (push)

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that you can format the output.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how.

Comment: Start by clicking the link in my previous comment or the "edit" link below your question.

Comment: That I understand. But how can I edit text so you can read it more easily?

Comment: Just like you wrote your original question. To start, the URLs won't be converted to a link if you put it in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164658/discussion-between-lloyd-r-prentice-and-code-apprentice).

Answer (score 10):

It appears you have not added your private key to your local machine's ssh agent. To do so follow these steps:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then follow the prompts for your key password, if you created it with one. If you created a key with a different file name and/or location, use it instead of `~.ssh/id_rsa`.

Comment: $ eval $(ssh-agent). Agent pid 16930 bash: .: filename argument required.: usage: . filename [arguments]    Is the filename it's asking for the file holding my public key? Thnx.

Comment: eval `ssh-agent' seemed to work; asked for pass phrase. ssh-add returned successfully. But attempt to  push local repository still doesn't work. Returns "Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: @LloydR.Prentice Please answer my questions in the comment below your question.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message. In my case some of the private keys had too open permissions.

I fixed it by changing the permissions for private keys to `600 (-rw-------)` and the public keys to `644 (-rw-r--r--)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ubuntu and have used Gitlab's manual for generating ssh keys, I must mention that there is a problem in the command they have provided. In that manual, keys has been generated using `-o` in `ssh-keygen` command, but keys generated by this command are not being supported by gnome-keyring. more information here:https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351742/306361